# Bootstrap DateTimePicker Set maxDate To The Second Field One Month After The First Field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have 2 date fields. One "From" and one "To".
I want when the user select from the first field the date ex "09/12/2015" the maxdate on the second field to be "09/01/2016". My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#from').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'});
        $('#to').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',useCurrent: false});

        $("#from").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#to').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });

        $("#to").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#from').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can you help me?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate date using Moment, so you will have:

```
$("#from").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#to').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  var nextMonth = e.date.add(1, 'months');
  $('#to').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(nextMonth);
});
```

Note that moment has a subtract method too, if you need to do the same operation in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#from").on("dp.change", function (e) {
  $('#to').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  var nextMonth = e.date.add(3, 'months');
  $('#to').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(nextMonth);
});
```

is failed when the maxdate belows 3 months